# Rules due to Annotations with JSON and Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have following JSON object

```
{"type":"success","value":{"id":5,"quote":"Spring Boot solves this problem. It gets rid of XML and wires up common components for me, so I don't have to spend hours scratching my head just to figure out how it's all pieced together."}}
```

and that code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject(
                    "http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);
            log.info(quote.toString());
        };
    }
}
```

---

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Value {

    private Long id;
    private String quote;

    public Value() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getQuote() {
        return this.quote;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setQuote(String quote) {
        this.quote = quote;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", quote='" + quote + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

---

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Quote {

    private String type;
    private Value value;

    public Quote() {
    }

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public String get22() {
        return type;
    }

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public void set22(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Quote{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Interesting is here the class Quote. First I noticed that the JSON form only delivers the object variables value and type without getter and setter.

So first I tried to remove these (getType() setType(String type)) from the class Quote and than the application was longer working.

Then I renamed the getters/setters to get22() set22 and it was also no longer working until I added the @JsonProperty annotation as you can see.

So it is obviously only working if the getters/setters are exactly named like:
getType() setType(String name) or have the Annotation @JsonProperty

My question is, what part of the program knows that the default getter setter has the syntax setType() getType(). 
Is it RestTemplate, or is it some magic behind spring or something else?

I tried also to find some answer with google to that and got confused by people saying jackson is involved here. I don't see a jackson declaration anywhere here.

To clarifiy:

If have that

```
   @JsonProperty("type")
public void set22(String type) {
    System.out.println("set");
    this.type = type;
}
```

It is clear to me why its working, because of the annotation.

If I remove set22 and add this

```
   public void setType(String type) {
    System.out.println("set");
    this.type = type;
}
```

It is also working!

But if i change the name of setType to setX then it is no longer working.

And I want to know why.

I really want to know what part here is responsible for the convertion from a JSON Obj. to a Java Object that I can learn more about the syntax rules for my further education.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what the question is. The JSON has an attribute named `type`. So Jackson looks for a bean property named `type`. That seems pretty natural to me. If you want to know how Jackson works, read the Jackson documentation.

Comment: My question is below the code with some example.

Comment: Spring uses Jackson to map Java objects to JSON and vice-versa. Jackson relies on standard Java bean conventions, and on annotations. Again, read the Jackson documentation.